# Picture wont load into div when using Flask

Tags: python, html, css, image, flask

I am creating a single page application but my #mainPicture will not load in the div its suppose to. This is where I am calling it in my **index.html**:

```
<body>

<div id="mainPicture">
    <div class="picture">
        <div id="headerTitle">Places I've Been</div>
        <div id="headerSubtext">A Blog About My Travels</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my code for linking stylesheet:

```
<link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static', filename='css/theme.css') }}">
```

And this is the CSS for it in my **theme.css**:

```
#mainPicture
{
    width:670px;
    height:497px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

#mainPicture.picture
{
    position:relative;
    width:650px;
    height:487px;
    top:10px;
    background-image:url(hudson1.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

It just shows up as a white space the size of the picture. I am using CMDER to run my webpage. The image hudson1.jpg is in the same folder as the theme.css also but it wont show it up in the div.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Are `hudson1.jpg` and `theme.css` in the same folder? If not, that's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is incorrect.

```
#mainPicture.picture
```

Is looking for an element with id mainPicture and class picture.  You should use:

```
#mainPicture > .picture
```

That will select the an element with a class of picture that is a child of an element with an id of mainPicture.